# How to efficiently create a large amount of QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I am developing a ground control station for a small drone, where I am trying to add a function to load waypoints from a file.
Each waypoint is a `QGraphicsItem` on the `QGraphicsScene`.

However, when there are more than 100 points in the file, the creation takes more than 2 seconds...

Is there any way to do this faster?

Comment: Do you need this class or can you simple use a pair of X / Y coordinate?

Comment: I need it because the waypoints need to be edited...

Comment: May be you can use the QGraphicsItemGroup (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitemgroup.html): The QGraphicsItemGroup class provides a container that treats a group of items as a single item ...

Comment: the problem for me is that to simply create that much items are slow...

Comment: implement a queue system that fires off another thread to create the points once the queue reaches a certain number

Comment: Which hardware are you running the application on? Is it a potato? But seriously, this takes around 1 millisecond on a desktop machine, and I can't imagine it taking much longer on a Pi, for example. Perhaps it is your waypoint loading code that is slow. We can't know for sure without seeing code.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in the view and not otherwise (i.e. file reading)? Did you use a profiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 40K Chips example shows off the population of a scene with a large number of elements.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-mainwindow-cpp.html

```
void MainWindow::populateScene()
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene;

    QImage image(":/qt4logo.png");

    // Populate scene
    int xx = 0;
    int nitems = 0;
    for (int i = -11000; i < 11000; i += 110) {
        ++xx;
        int yy = 0;
        for (int j = -7000; j < 7000; j += 70) {
            ++yy;
            qreal x = (i + 11000) / 22000.0;
            qreal y = (j + 7000) / 14000.0;

            QColor color(image.pixel(int(image.width() * x), int(image.height() * y)));
            QGraphicsItem *item = new Chip(color, xx, yy);
            item->setPos(QPointF(i, j));
            scene->addItem(item);

            ++nitems;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a lot of initialization code going on in here, then it may take a long time.  You may want to look into subclassing your `QGraphicsItem` if it is slow loading.  The level of detail argument in the custom item here (see chip.cpp) is pretty cool how it handles everything.

Hope that helps.